# How should my wife apply for a Schengen visa if I am going to work there for a few months?

Tags: schengen, work, belgium, spouses

I am an Indian passport holder, awaiting receipt of my work permit from Employer to work in Belgium for a tenure of less than three months.

I want my wife to accompany my during this time, so that we can spend some time to explore Europe.

The challenge for me currently is: We need to manage the visa application for my wife.

I am wondering what would be the correct and fastest way to get visa done for her, whether to apply her visa as a dependent, but this would entail long waiting time as I would be expected to arrive in Belgium first and then would be expected to send an invite(please correct me, if this can be applied and done differently and preferably together)

or to apply her visa as a normal tourist visa. In such case, I am thinking whether it would be ideal to mention about my work permit in her tourist visa application or not.

Comment: Rhetorically, would your wife have a reason to travel to Belgium if you were not there? So you would support her premise to the extent possible. I.e., provide your work permit details along with the associated accommodation arrangements.

Comment: @GayotFow thanks for answering. So we can still apply her Visa as a tourist Type 'C' [and not as family visit Visa, as we are planning to go together ], and in the cover letter we can provide my work permit details. Can you please clear my understanding on this, would it be a genuine case, if we present her application in such manner?

Comment: In the Schengen world, it's the same form and everything is type "C". There is no distinct category of 'family visit visa', it's all Schengen Short Stay.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer (and then accept it), or delete the question.

Answer (score 4):

I return to share that this issue has been resolved. I went ahead and mentioned my work permit and assignment details in my wife's visa application, alongside mentioning the purpose of her visit as tourist + accompanying a work permit holder. She got the visa for the requested number of days.

Comment: Thank you; too few questioners come back to explain the resolution.